# Python: is 'int' a type or a function?

Tags: python

I did this in Python 3.4:

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
>>> int(0)
0
```

Now I am wondering what int actually is. Is it a type, or is it a function? Is it both? If it is both, is it also true that all types can be called like functions?

Comment: `type(int)` returns `type`. `int(0)` creates an object of type `int`.

Comment: Im not familiar with python at all but it looks like an object

Comment: All types/classes in Python are generally [callables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) (function-like) as well.

Comment: @SamOrozco Well, *everything* in Python is an object, including types and functions, so that doesn't really answer this question. It's pretty much like saying "it's a thing."

Answer (score 15):

`int` is a **[class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html)**. The type of a class is usually `type`.

And yes, *almost* all classes can be called like functions. You create what's called an **instance** which is an object that behaves as you defined in the class. They can have their own functions and have special attributes.

(`type` is also a class if you're interested but it's a special class. It's a bit complicated but you can read more on it if you'll search for metaclasses)

Reference: [Python documentation for the `int` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 5):

`int` is a built-in class/type:

```
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True
```

---

When you invoke `int('123')`, Python finds out that `int` itself is nota function, but then attempts to call `int.__call__('123')`; this itself resolves to  `type.__dict__['__call__']`; this is called with `(int, '123')` as arguments. The default `__call__` implementation of `type` tries to construct a new object of the type given as the first argument (here `int`, by calling the `__new__` method on that type class; thus the behaviour of `int('123')` indirectly comes from `int.__new__(int, '123')`, which constructs a new `int` instance that has the value of the given string parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a class. You can use help function, it is a wrapper around pydocs.

```
help(int)
```

Help on class int in module builtins:

```
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
 |  numbers, this truncates towards zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's both. In Python, the types have associated functions of the same name, that coerce their argument into objects of the named type, if it can be done.  So, the type `int` `<type 'int'>`has a function `int` along with it.

Comment: I couldn't find a confirmation for this. May I ask you to expand your answer a bit with some evidence and/or references?

Comment: I don't think it is both. It is callable, and calls `__new__` and `__init__` on the class object if they exist.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Read this: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/

Comment: The implementation of the so called native types has evolved over time and as far as I remember the answer is not completely wrong, it just apllies to acient Python versions (before 2).

Comment: Hey guys: mathematically, what is an entity that maps a value in the set called its *domain* uniquely to a value in another set, called its *range*?

Comment: @KlausD. Right. `type(3) is int` is false in Python 2.1, but true since the first stage of type/class unification in Python 2.2 (which was released in 2001). So this answer is only about 15 years out of date. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when an integer is defined in a Python script like this one?

```
>>> a=1
>>> a
1
```

When you execute the first line, the function `PyInt_FromLong` is called and its logic is the following:

```
if integer value in range -5,256:
    return the integer object pointed by the small integers array at the
    offset (value + 5).
else:
    if no free integer object available:
        allocate new block of integer objects
    set value of the next free integer object in the current block
    of integers.
    return integer object
```

If you really want to dig deeper into this, and know how `int` works in Python, visit [Python integer objects implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/) which I referred for answering this.

Answer (score -2):

It's a class i.e type obviously.

But if you are confused with its use like a function, I have answer here.

It's because, in earlier versions of Python, when it was introduced, int() was a function. It might have returned an integer (in my thought). But later int() function was no longer developed

Comment: Do you have any citations for "when it was introduced, int() was a function" and "later int() function was no longer developed"?

Comment: @Brian https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node26.html#SECTION003300000000000000000